# Change the comma separator to colon between the year and the page in citation?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, punctuation

I am new to latex so I would appreciate some help. I am following Harvard referencing style as my reference style. I am trying to configure my `natbib` package so that it separates the year and the referencing pages with a colon and not comma. For example, currently this code:

```
\citep[23]{bell2005}
```

produces this:

```
(Bell,  2005,  23).
```

Which is confusing. I am trying to produce the following style:

```
(Bell, 2005: 23)
```

Any advice please?

Comment: The correct term for `:` in English is 'colon' not 'column' (which is why I rolled back your edit.)

Comment: @AlanMunn thank you for clearing out the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change these parameters with the `\setcitestyle` macro, as described in §2.9 of the `natbib` documentation.

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
```