# natbib: change separator between year and pages in in-text citations

Tags: citing, natbib

I have an in-text citation of the structure author (year, page) and want the *comma* to be replaced by a *colon* (i.e. `author (year: page)`) - and do the same for a citation of the style author (year, page), respectively).

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib} % for reference management
\begin{document}
    Citation using "cite": \cite[10-11]{Lastname.1999}. \newline
    Citation using "citet": \citet[10-11]{Lastname.1999}.
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\bibliography{Lit_tmp}
\end{document}
```

The content of `Lit_tmp.bib` is:

```
@article{Lastname.1999,
    author = {Lastname, Firstname},
    year = {1999},
    title = {The title of the article},
    pages = {123--456},
    volume = {87},
    number = {3},
    journal = {Journal Name},
}
```

I want the commas in the output (highlighted in yellow) to be replaced by columns - how do I achieve this?
[image: Output]

Comment: Does this solution solve your problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349054/change-the-comma-separator-to-colon-between-the-year-and-the-page-in-citation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's question was solved in the comments.

Comment: Would it not have been more sensible to close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349054/35864?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the solution suggested in a question referenced in the comments, `\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}` solved the issue.

*EDIT*

To avoid needing `natbit`, use `\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}` to print "year: pages" in-text and `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}` to omit the "p. "